# JMeter Stops sending requests

Tags: jmeter

I have run jmeter script for 1500 users. It starts sending request but after some time it get stops with out showing any progress. Also test doesn't stop at end time.

Non-GUI mode console status is as follows:

```
summary +    280 in   112s =    2.5/s Avg: 45551 Min: 42988 Max: 84385 Err:   278 (99.29%) Active: 450 Started: 1500 Finished: 1050

summary =  14812 in  1439s =   10.3/s Avg: 77248 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 12806 (86.46%)

summary +    239 in   114s =    2.1/s Avg: 47256 Min: 38723 Max: 88772 Err:   236 (98.74%) Active: 440 Started: 1500 Finished: 1060

summary =  15051 in  1469s =   10.2/s Avg: 76771 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 13042 (86.65%)
summary +    264 in   115s =    2.3/s Avg: 48766 Min: 40408 Max: 87471 Err:   263 (99.62%) Active: 430 Started: 1500 Finished: 1070

summary =  15315 in  1499s =   10.2/s Avg: 76289 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 13305 (86.88%)
summary +    111 in   111s =    1.0/s Avg: 55518 Min: 40488 Max: 98316 Err:   108 (97.30%) Active: 422 Started: 1500 Finished: 1078

summary =  15426 in  1530s =   10.1/s Avg: 76139 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 13413 (86.95%)
summary +    163 in   129s =    1.3/s Avg: 72461 Min: 58026 Max: 111970 Err:   159 (97.55%) Active: 405 Started: 1500 Finished: 1095

summary =  15589 in  1559s =   10.0/s Avg: 76101 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 13572 (87.06%)
summary +    113 in   141s =    0.8/s Avg: 78260 Min: 69917 Max: 118153 Err:   112 (99.12%) Active: 386 Started: 1500 Finished: 1114

summary =  15702 in  1590s =    9.9/s Avg: 76116 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 13684 (87.15%)
summary +    104 in   159s =    0.7/s Avg: 93311 Min: 85408 Max: 146444 Err:    99 (95.19%) Active: 350 Started: 1500 Finished: 1150

summary =  15806 in  1620s =    9.8/s Avg: 76229 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 13783 (87.20%)
summary +    151 in   173s =    0.9/s Avg: 91366 Min: 85043 Max: 159224 Err:   147 (97.35%) Active: 306 Started: 1500 Finished: 1194

summary =  15957 in  1650s =    9.7/s Avg: 76373 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 13930 (87.30%)
summary +    178 in   186s =    1.0/s Avg: 84192 Min: 56634 Max: 165018 Err:   165 (92.70%) Active: 227 Started: 1500 Finished: 1273
summary =  16135 in  1679s =    9.6/s Avg: 76459 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 14095 (87.36%)

summary +    208 in    89s =    2.3/s Avg: 44723 Min: 25609 Max: 63280 Err:   193 (92.79%) Active: 103 Started: 1500 Finished: 1397
summary =  16343 in  1709s =    9.6/s Avg: 76055 Min:   682 Max: 168072 Err: 14288 (87.43%)
```

Comment: check sys util of machine which you are using for load generation. maybe its not capable of taking that much load.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into summarizer results, you're getting around 90% failures. Unlikely that it is expected. So I would recommend the following:

1. Check `jmeter.log` file for any warnings or errors
2. Make sure that you have disabled all listeners
3. Run test with fewer number of threads until errors start to occur. Examine application logs to see what the problem is. As an option you can temporarily tell JMeter to store response data for failed samples by setting `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true` property in *user.properties* or *jmeter.properties* file.
4. Make sure that you're following recommendations from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips)
5. Monitor server and load generator (JMeter) machine health. If load generator cannot create such a load you may have to consider switching to [distributed testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

Comment: No, its also happening for 0% faliures results. There is no action happens on non gui mode for 4 hours, it seems like jmeter got hang. And how can i stop test in non gui mode forcefully if something like this happens, because test doesn't stop in given duration??